# Problem connecting my user to my SPRING/ANGULAR application

Tags: angular, spring, connection

Good afternoon,

I am currently working as a novice on a spring (back-end) and angular (front-end) application. I'm at the user connection part of my application, I'm almost finished but I have one last problem that I can't solve at all.

In fact when I enter identifiers in my form it takes them into account but I have the impression that the back refuses to let me through even though I authorized access in my security config file on the back!

**Here is the error during inspection :**

`core.mjs:11483  ERROR  HttpErrorResponse error :  {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>…, text: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n  <head>\n    <met…n in</button>\n      </form>\n</div>\n</body></html>'} headers :  HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ} message :  "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:7070/login" name :  "HttpErrorResponse" ok :  false status :  200 statusText :  "OK" url :  "http://localhost:7070/login" [[Prototype]] :  HttpResponseBase constructor :  class HttpErrorResponse [[Prototype]] :  Object`

**Here is my security configuration in spring :**

```
    `package com.tracker.EsportTracker.config;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
    import         org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
    import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
    import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
    import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.StaticHeadersWriter;
    import com.tracker.EsportTracker.service.impl.AppUserDetailsService;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
@Autowired
private AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(ar -> ar.requestMatchers("/users").permitAll())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(ar -> ar.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                    .permitAll());
}
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:4200/"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

}`

To summarize on the front side I call localhost:7070/users to get the list of users and I am redirected to localhost:7070/login

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
In you **SecurityConfig**

```
@Bean 
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .authorizeHttpRequests( ar -> 
                ar.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                ar.requestMatchers("/users").permitAll()
                ar.anyRequest().authenticated()
         ).formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build()

}
```

Comment: You can learn a lot about Spring security here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/index.html

Comment: it still doesn't work, I have the same error